# How do I make links in a textview clickable inside a listview

Tags: android

How can  I make links in a textview clickable inside a listview When I use auto link ="web" I cant click the list item . It goes directly to the web url .I am fetching online contents. How can I resolve this issue. Any help please..

Comment: It will be difficult imho, because ListView lines are not 'real view' (they are generally made of one view which is reused for every line), and you'll have to treat the onItemClick event yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Implement the `onClick` event on the `TextView(URL)` of the `ListView Item`, in the Adapter's `getView()` method.

check the code in the question here:

[Make different clickable views on a listview item in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559575/make-different-clickable-views-on-a-listview-item-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

This method works with Mixed text and link. 
In adapter getView

```
yourTextView.setText("http://www.example.com");
Linkify.addLinks(yourTextView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `view.requestFocus()` for the view u want to click...